# Webサイトに埋め込んでいるreCAPTCHA v3が、正しく成功しない

Tags: php, recaptcha

#### 起きている問題

WebサイトにreCAPTCHA v3を埋め込もうとしております。
検証環境と本番環境（異なるレンタルサーバー）を用意し、全く同じWebサイトデータを再現しています。(PHP Ver.7.4)
両サイトで同じreCAPTCHAを連携。同一キー、同一プログラムでreCAPTCHAが成功しているかの検証行ったところ、

- 本番環境：100%の確率でreCAPTCHAが失敗
- 検証環境：100%の確率でreCAPTCHAが成功

となり、本番環境でのみ、reCAPCHAが成功せず困っております。

**ソースコード**
フォームのformタグの後ろに、次のコードを記述し、reCAPCHAを検証しております。

```
<script>
// reCAPTCHAのコールバック関数
function onSubmit(token) {
// reCAPTCHAトークンを非表示フィールドにセット
document.getElementById("recaptchaResponse").value = token;

// フォームを送信
document.getElementById("contact_form").submit();
}
</script>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// フォームが送信された場合の処理

// フォームデータを取得
$form_title = $_POST['form_title'];
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$phonetic = $_POST['phonetic'];
// ... 他のフォームフィールドの取得 ...

// Google reCAPTCHA v3のSecret keyを指定
$secretKey = 'XXXXXX';

// reCAPTCHAのトークンを取得
$recaptchaToken = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];

// reCAPTCHAのトークンをGoogleに送信して検証
$recaptchaUrl = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$recaptchaData = array(
'secret' => $secretKey,
'response' => $recaptchaToken
);

$recaptchaOptions = array(
'http' => array(
'method' => 'POST',
'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'content' => http_build_query($recaptchaData)
)
);

$recaptchaContext = stream_context_create($recaptchaOptions);
$recaptchaResult = file_get_contents($recaptchaUrl, false, $recaptchaContext);
$recaptchaResponse = json_decode($recaptchaResult);

// reCAPTCHAが成功しているかを確認
if ($recaptchaResponse->success) {
// reCAPTCHAが成功した場合
// 成功メッセージを表示
echo "成功";
} else {
// reCAPTCHAが失敗した場合
// エラーメッセージを表示
}
}
?>
```

#### 問題解決するために試したこと

$recaptchaContext、$recaptchaResult、$recaptchaResponseの値の取得内容を確認したところ、以下のような結果になりました。

【検証環境】

```
$recaptchaContext→Resource id #20
$recaptchaResult→ { "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2023-08-21T01:51:38Z", "hostname": "link-web.net", "score": 0.9 }
$recaptchaResponse→Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/link-web/www/zenko/wp-content/themes/sanko/contact.php:1221 Stack trace: #0 /home/link-web/www/zenko/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include() #1 /home/link-web/www/zenko/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/link-web/...') #2 /home/link-web/www/zenko/index.php(17): require('/home/link-web/...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/link-web/www/zenko/wp-content/themes/sanko/contact.php on line 1221
```

【本番環境】

```
$recaptchaContext→Resource id #717
$recaptchaResult→ 空
$recaptchaResponse→ 空
```

Resource idの値が違っているのでここが糸口になるのかと思うのですが、このResource idが何を示しているのかがわかりませんでした。

このResource idの件を含め、問題解決につながるアドバイスをいただけますと幸いです。